# '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object is not iterable in Python 3.4

Tags: python, regex, pos-tagger

When I use Brill Tagger, I get this error.

```
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object is not iterable
WARNING:root:2016-04-05 00:05:37.503718 is when this event was logged.
ERROR:root:'_sre.SRE_Pattern' object is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dropbox\VCL\MyWrapper.py", line 137, in run_alg
    CLC_POS.tag_file(input_utf8, path_out + '.pos', file_encoding, CLC_POS.load_tagger('pos_tbl_86943.model'), '')
  File "D:\Dropbox\VCL\CLC_POS.py", line 277, in tag_file
    token_tag = tagger.tag(word_list)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\brill.py", line 264, in tag
    tagged_tokens = self._initial_tagger.tag(tokens)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 61, in tag
    tags.append(self.tag_one(tokens, i, tags))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 81, in tag_one
    tag = tagger.choose_tag(tokens, index, history)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 546, in choose_tag
    for regexp, tag in self._regexs:
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object is not iterable
```

In sequential.py, I get error when it comes to **for** loop.

```
def choose_tag(self, tokens, index, history):
    for regexp, tag in self._regexs:
        if re.match(regexp, tokens[index]):
            return tag
    return None
```

I run this same code a month ago and there was no error.
*sequential.py* belongs to nltk files, does that means I should mess with it?

What have I done wrong? Please provide a fix if possible.

Comment: `self._regexs` is not a list. It is **one** compiled regular expression object.

Comment: I can't provide a fix, because without your code that creates the `tagger` and otherwise interacts with it, we can't tell you what might have cased that list to be replaced with a single regular expression object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple.

We just need to train the data again to get new model.

I think problem is some changes in NLTK, but not sure where it is. Besides, this only affects Brill Tagger, not CRF Tagger.

Answer (score 5):

`self._regexs` is not an iterable object (like a list or a tuple). It is **one** compiled regular expression object.

Somewhere else in your code, you did something that effectively ends up doing something a lot like this:

```
self._regexs = re.compile(r'...')
```

It could be that you passed in a single item somewhere where the `nltk` API expected a sequence of such objects. I don't see any obvious way for the `nltk` code to have done this however.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. But I didn't use compile anywhere. I created a lot of expression string and I added them to a list. Then I use a list to make a RegexpTagger. That is the only part I use Regex.

Comment: @Alex: yes, and something has replaced `tagger._regexs` with a single object. I can't see any code *in `nltk`* that would do this however.